# how can one put a shadow around an iterm2 window

Tags: iterm2

In iterm2 Build 3.3.2 under defaults, if several windows are open, their
boundaries are difficult to distinguish visually. All windows are uniformly the same color. There is no shading around the edges. Thus, their edges cannot be distinguished. Placing the mouse on the edge of a window to resize it is difficult because I can't see where one window ends and the one behind it begins.

By contrast, in macos Terminal version 2.9.5, a window throws a shadow at its edge, which makes resizing by mouse fairly easy.

Is there a way to do this in iterm2? I do not see a way to do this in iterm2, profiles, window tab.

Comment: I know this is old... I haven't found the answer to this yet but I can tell you you can add a border to the window. **Preferences > Appearance > Windows > Show border around windows**. This way the window has a border but there isn't any shadow as the other windows in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the answer to this...

There are two different settings that work together for the window shadow to work.

## First: enable shadow on transparency

*Read the second part if this setting doesn't work.*

There is an option to disable the window shadow if the window has transparency.

1. In Preferences > Advanced search for shadow.
2. Then select "No" where it says 'Disable the window shadow on [DEPENDING ON YOUR SYSTEM] when the window has a transparent session to prevent text shadows.'
   [image: iTerm2 shadow options]

## Second: play with the transparency

If you have selected "Yes" in the first part there will be no shadow in the window if there is transparency. To test it:

1. Go to Preferences > Profiles > Select profile on the left > Window.
2. Play with the "Transparency:" slider under "Window appearance", see the shadow disappear.

If you selected "No" in the first part and you still don't get any shadow, try the steps above and play with the "Transparency" slider. I guess this resets the shadow.

[image: iTerm2 opacity]